# getEntity() returns null, readEntity(InputStream.class) loads everything to memory

Tags: java, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I have problem downloading file (getting the input stream) from server (quarkus implementation) in client (quarkus implementation)

I am using 2.9.2.Final version of Quarkus for both client and server,
dependency - quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson

I have a server which returns InputStream inside Response:

```
  @Override
  public Response downloadFileById(String id) {
    var inputStream = repo.downloadFileByFileId(id);
    return Response.ok(inputStream, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
        .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename = \"" + fileName + "\"")
        .header("Content-Length", repo.getFileLengthByFileById(id))
        .build();
  }
```

On client side, I've tried these variations:

This works but loads everything into memory. It uses **ByteArrayInputStream** inside ClientSendRequestHandler.java from package org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.client.handlers; (see line **340** in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/b0019c087880f9fd1371776b8c23c1b49129dcb3/independent-projects/resteasy-reactive/client/runtime/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/reactive/client/handlers/ClientSendRequestHandler.java)

```
var stream = service.downloadFileById(id)
                    .await()
                    .indefinitely()
                    .readEntity(InputStream.class);
```

I expected this to work but it returns null

```
var stream = service
              .downloadFileById(id)
              .await()
              .indefinitely()
              .getEntity();
```

As I am going through following method from the ClientSendRequestHandler.java

```
private void attachSentHandlers(Future<HttpClientResponse> sent,
        HttpClientRequest httpClientRequest,
        RestClientRequestContext requestContext)
```

I am wondering, is it not supported?
I see cases for Multipart data, File, and an else branch
Not sure what am I missing.

Comment: Have you tried using a `Uni<File>` as a return type?

Comment: I tried service.downloadFileById(id)
                    .await()
                    .indefinitely()
                    .readEntity(File.class);
It is first loaded to memory, than to file...
When I am trying this with imperative client (quarkus-rest-client-jackson), it works fine in case downloadFileById does not return Uni. When it does, error occurs, complaining about "Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/octet-stream and type interface io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni"

Comment: My point is that you should not use `Response` in this case. If you use `Uni<File>` things should just work.

Comment: I have tried scenario where server returns Uni<File>, specifically Uni.createFrom().item(file); client consuming Uni<File>.
Sending over 2gb file.

here are my observations:
- server: memory consumption is increased drastically upon sending to client
- client: correctly receiving to tmp file but doesn't get whole file when working with over 2gb, instead I got only fragments(60 mb, another try 3 mb)
the client worked ok when I sent smaller file (100 mb).

Comment: correction here, client gets the tmp file completely... , just the problem with server memory remains